# Why am I not getting the Milliner hat?

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2020

I have 11 hats now over a few sites (Which I'm very proud about) and I knew that you can get the Milliner hat if you have a 11 hats. But I haven't received the hat yet.

This is the hat I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get 11 hats over a specific site to achieve the Milliner Hat

Comment: Also note that clicking on `About this hat`, will tell you this.